# Biztalk2016 The mapping does not exist. For Config Store applications, the config info has not been set

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have migrated a biztalk project from Biztalk 2009 to Biztalk 2016 and .NET 4.6.2. In old version, everything works fine, but in new version, I get an error with WCF-Custom adapter.

```
A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port "PhySndGuiExportResponsePort" with URI "net.msmq://serviceserver/private/EwrServicesInQueue" is suspended. 
 Error details: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The mapping does not exist. For Config Store applications, the config info has not been set.

   at Microsoft.BizTalk.SSOClient.Interop.ISSOConfigStore.GetConfigInfo(String applicationName, String identifier, Int32 flags, IPropertyBag properties)
   at SSOSettingsFileManager.SSOHelper.GetConfigInfo(String affiliateApplication, Boolean enableRemoteAccess)
   at SSOSettingsFileManager.SSOSettingsManager.GetSettings(String affiliateApplication, Boolean enableRemoteAccess)
   at SSOSettingsFileManager.SSOSettingsFileReader.Read(String affiliateApplication, Boolean enableRemoteAccess)
   at SSOSettingsFileManager.SSOSettingsFileReader.ReadString(String affiliateApplication, String valueName)
   at DAP.IdentityModel.Selectors.ForwardingDAPClientCredentials..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Converters.BehaviorFactory.ApplyEndpointBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String wcfExtensions, String endpointBehaviorConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Config.CustomTLConfig.ApplyEndpointBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.CreateChannelFactory[TChannel](IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.InitializeValues(IBaseMessage message)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2..ctor(IBaseMessage message, WcfTransmitter`2 transmitter)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfTransmitter`2.GetClientFromCache(String spid, IBaseMessage message)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfAsyncBatch`2.BatchWorker(List`1 messages) 
 MessageId:  {DC4E26FC-B65B-4AE6-B2F3-01AFC5B85D6F}
 InstanceID: {94A91D61-D8BE-4F74-8B06-1B4C58B36CEA}
```

The sendport PhySndGuiExportResponsePort is using PassThroTransmit send pipeline, transport type WCF-Custom with certificate authentication.

Run ssomanage tool see that the mapping is BtsDeploymentProperties, but not a GUID as the others. Can this cause the error?

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On>ssomanage.exe -listmappings tvn.Infra
Using SSO server : biztalk2016server

Existing mappings for application 'tvn.Infra' -

(E) $ConfigStore$\BtsDeploymentProperties     : BtsDeploymentProperties

Any idea to solve it is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this port using a map? If it is, I would check it because there are some changes in mapping engine between those versions.

Comment: Yes, I have a logical port and map to a physical one which is deployed. I editted my question with the mapping.

Comment: Sorry, I mean a map between messages, not the binding. Open the port in the BizTalk Administration Console, and check if there are something in the section Outbound Maps.

Comment: Ah, sorry, no Outbound Maps.

Comment: Same for Inbound maps?

Comment: It has no Inbound map

Comment: How did you create the port? Imported using bindings from your old environment or from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with the WCF adapter or the port, it's with some custom code that's trying to use `SSOSettingsFileReader` (from BTDF) to read SSO:

> at DAP.IdentityModel.Selectors.ForwardingDAPClientCredentials..ctor()

I would look into your constructor code there, find out what SSO application name and key it's trying to find, and go from there.  Chances are you didn't properly deploy your SSO config store - for example, from the command line (since the extension doesn't work in VS2015 at this point):

```
MSBuild.exe <btdfproj file path> /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug /t:DeploySSO
```

Comment: In the constructor, only one call: SSOSettingsFileReader.ReadString(SSO_APP_NAME, LOCAL_ISSUER_ADDRESS), I double-checked, both app name and value is existing. This statement throw exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: I found one more thing that even my Biztalk application was deployed sucessfully, but when I use ssomanage.exe -listapps, it return me "No applications available for <My Domain User>"

Comment: Try using the BTDF SSOSettingsEditor.exe to see if it can find your app name.  Make sure your app is properly getting deployed.

Comment: Using BTDF, the application existing but the tool also throws the same error "The mapping does not exist. For Config Store applications, the config info has not been set."

Comment: Yes, I tried to unconfigure biztalk (also SSO) an configure again. Or you mention another way to redeploying?

Comment: Use the BTDF process to deploy the SSO app - for example, `MSBuild.exe <btdfproj file path> /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug /t:DeploySSO`